# How do I get database rows from a custom table using wpdb?

Tags: database, wpdb

I'm trying to get particular rows from custom table into an object using wpdb.

From the cli of the mysql client, this line yields the rows I want:

```
select * from wp_94b3c05783_wpforms_entries WHERE entry_id IN ( 738,  552, 551   )
```

This is my translation of that instruction into a wpdb call:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}wpforms_entries WHERE ID IN( 738, 552, 551  )"  );
```

Inspecting $results using 'var_dump' returns an empty array.

So, the mysql query works - but when I wrap it in a wpdb call I get nothing back.

I'm definitely testing the queries against the same database as the WordPress instance is using.

Comment: have you declare global $wpdb variable on top of your code? global $wpdb;

Comment: Sorry, yes. I should have included that in the initial post. I'll edit it (if I can figure out how to)

Comment: ok. try passing an array instead of values directly in "IN()"

Comment: I changed that part of the line to: "... IN( [738])". I'm still getting an empty array back unfortunately.

Comment: First try echoing the sql string, see if its correct. Second in the top query you check `entry_id` but in the bottom you check `ID`, is that correct?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast: that's correct - I didn't spot the difference between 'ID' and 'entry_id'. So technically they are different queries! Whoops.... However, when I correct that, I still get an empty array back.

Comment: do `echo "SELECT * FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}wpforms_entries WHERE ID IN( 738, 552, 551  )"`, see what it outputs. My quess is the `$wpdb->prefix` only outputs `wp_` and not `wp_94b3c05783_`

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Yes, I'm pretty sure the sql string is correct. Here's a comparison: http://pastie.org/p/5V9UkIH7xR4wRfFL9iscW8

Comment: `IN` should be `( 738,  552, 551 )` and not `( [738,  552, 551] )`, im guessing its also comes as a variable?. If thats the case you can do `implode(',', $variable_name)`

Comment: @Buttered_Toast: that does it! Thank you!...

... but that's an odd one. I swear I was getting an empty array back before I edited the parameter to be an array.... so I think that adding a space after IN might also have been important. Thank you!

Comment: @Buttered_Toast: no, adding the space probably wasn't the initial problem. I just deleted the space and got back the expected results... so the initial issue most likely was my use of 'ID' instead of 'entry_id'. Thanks again.